# spring security- How to invoke controller method for authentication & authorization on login

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I need to integrate Spring security in an existing Spring MVC project (Spring 3.2.13 +MyBatis+PostgreSQL). I'm new to Spring Security.

I'm able to login into the application when credentials are hard-coded into the spring-security.xml (Spring Security 3.2.5).
But, in the existing implementation (without spring security), controller authenticates & based on user status, redirects to respective JSP
**Here is the Controller :**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processLogin(@ModelAttribute(value="loginUser")UserForm user, Model model) {
//Spring Validation here
...
User authenticatedUser = userMgmtService.processUserLogin(loggedInUser);

if(authenticatedUser!= null){               
            if(authenticatedUser.getStatus().equals(UserStatusConstants.USER_ACTIVE)){
                if(authenticatedUser.getAdminFlag()){
                    viewName= "redirect:/admin/adminHome.html";
                }               
                else{
                    viewName= "redirect:/home.html";
                }
            }
            else if(authenticatedUser.getStatus().equals(UserStatusConstants.USER_NEW)){
                viewName="redirect:/changePassword.html";
            }
            else if(authenticatedUser.getStatus().equals(UserStatusConstants.USER_LOCKED)){
                    viewName="redirect:/accountLockedOut.html";
            }
            else if(authenticatedUser.getStatus().equals(UserStatusConstants.USER_INACTIVE)){
                viewName="redirect:/accessDenied.html";
            }

            model.addAttribute("loginUser",authenticatedUser);
        }

 return viewName;
```

**Here is the User Class :**

```
@Component
public class User {

    private String userName;

    private String password;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    /** Flag whether the user is admin or not */
    private Boolean adminFlag;

    /** Status Num for New, Active, Locked, Inactive */
    private Integer status;

    private Date lastLoginTimestamp;

    //Getters & Setters
    ....
}
```

Roles : I have just two roles in the system SUPERUSER (when adminFlag = true) and APPUSER (when adminFlag = false). And Status 0=New, 1=Active, 2=Locked, 3=Inactive

**Here is my USER Database Table :**
 [image]

**My spring-security.xml :**

```
 <!-- Bypass security for resources - css,images,scripts  -->
   <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>

   <http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_APPUSER,ROLE_SUPERUSER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/forgotPassword*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_APPUSER,ROLE_SUPERUSER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_APPUSER,ROLE_SUPERUSER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/" access="ROLE_SUPERUSER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_APPUSER"/>

    <form-login login-page="/login.html"                
                login-processing-url="/login"
                authentication-failure-url="/login.html?autherror=true"
                username-parameter="userName"
                password-parameter="password"
                default-target-url="/home.html"
                always-use-default-target="false"/>
    <logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,user" logout-success-url="/logout"/>       
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied"/>     
    <session-management>
                <!-- Listener HttpSessionEventPublisher (in web.xml) notifies of concurrent sessions -->
                <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
     </session-management>


       </http>

  <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user1" password="123" authorities="ROLE_APPUSER"/>
                <user name="superuser" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_SUPERUSER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>   
  </authentication-manager>
```

**Requirement :** How to use spring-security to perform the controller logic shown above? What changes do I need to make in the existing implementation?

Answer (score 2):

There are several other ways, the easiest way in my opinion is to create a new authentication provider. So we simply need to implement the AuthenticationProvider interface.

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        if (name.equals("admin") && password.equals("system")) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);
            return auth;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Then add the following line in your authentication provider in spring-security.xml

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>
```